# Is $(H,*)$ a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a few problems like this and am not sure how to get started.  If I can see how to do one, I'm sure I can figure them all out.  Here's the problem.

We have $G = ( \mathbb{R}, +)$ and $H = \{$ log $a: a \in \mathbb{Q}, a >0\}$.   Is $H$ a subgroup of $G$?

I know that I need to prove that $i^{-1} + j \in H$ but I'm not sure how, for $i,j\in H$.   I guess I'm not sure what $i^{-1}$ would be in $H$.  $i=$ (log $a)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're considering inverses under the inherited group operation. Here, the inverse is the additive inverse, so what you're asking for is $-\log a + \log b \in H$ for any $\log a, \log b \in H$ (along with $H$ nonempty of course, but this is obvious).

But if $\log a, \log b \in H$, we know that $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a, b > 0$. For $-\log a + \log b$ to then be in $H$ is, of course, the same as asking for $\log (a^{-1}b) \in H$, which is the same as asking for $a^{-1}b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a^{-1}b > 0$. Given our choice of $a$ and $b$, this is true.

Comment: Maybe $-\log a+log b=\log(a^{-1}b)$.

Comment: Um, $\log a^{-1}+\log b$ is certainly not $\log(a^{-1}+b)$.

Comment: I figured it out.  You were right.  I was looking at the inverse all wrong.  The inverse the additive inverse.  This means that the inverse of element $x \in H$ where $x=$log $a$ for some $a \in G$ is -log $a$.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Since the operation taken is *sum*, you must show $\;H\;$ is closed under sum:

$$\log a\,,\,\log b\in H\stackrel ?\implies \log a-\log b\in H \;?$$

Perhaps this is a good moment to remember some logarithmic properties:

$$\begin{align*}\log a+\log b&=\log ab\\
\log a-\log b&=\log\frac ab\\
\log(a^n)&=n\log a\end{align*}$$